# How to set type dynamically in typescript using 'es6' style?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking for a smart way to structure my code (ES6 style). Without if statement.

My angular component app-slider has an attribute what enables the component to get data from the parent (using @Input); The value that comes into the app-slider component is wither 'city' or 'event'.

The two child component

```
<app-slider [context]="'city'"></app-slider>
<app-slider [context]="'event'"></app-slider>
```

The purpose of the two are the same - they display some information - either about cities or about events.

Based on the value 'city' or 'event' I would like to call my mongo db to fetch the corresponding data.

I can easily call my database layer in my constructer and call either getCities() or getEvents(). I can use an if statement.

But would it be possible to it without an if statement - a more clean way?

Thanks again

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense. Is there more to it that's missing?

Comment: *"The incomming string will tell my angular component which interface should be used to the html"* I'm curious what you mean there. Remember that TypeScript type information is almost entirely removed prior to the code actually running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create dictionary :
dict = {
event: Event,
city: City}
then
var data = dict[stringType];
// Event or City

Comment: Okay, so the Event or City will reference to one of the interfaces?

Comment: Im not sure for Typescript, if they are functions you shhould call the specific function Event or City.  In your case can you do similar to this: database[fn]() like that? fn will be the string getCities or getEvents from the dictionary

Comment: It sounds like an elegant solutions. Could you provide a cohesive example?

Comment: var string = 'getCities'; var result = db[string]();  string variable is coming from the incoming string and db is your database access. But you should do some modifications if needed for angular. if the string is getEvents it will call db.getEvents method. You can try it